# Parsing txt file to List

Tags: c#

I have a txt file that want to store into a array. I'm running into a problem parsing when I have additional items on single line, as the pipe(|) would indicate another item to be stored.

```
Inv #     Date     term qty description         price Tax
3221409:2017/01/12:215|10:WD2002:2TB Hard Drive:121.66:N|20:KG240S:240GB SSD:125.10:N|20:KG120S:120GB SSD:78.75:N
```

I'm trying to first try to open the file and show each element to the console. getting index outside the bounds of the array. The file doesn't have headers I provided them for information.
 //this object lets you read from a file.
            StreamReader streamReader = null;

```
        string lineData;
        string[] lineElements;

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Woohoo file found");
            try
            {
                int invoice;
                String invoicedate;
                int term;
                int qty;
                string description;
                Boolean tax;


                streamReader = new StreamReader(path);
                while (streamReader.Peek() > 0)
                {
                    lineData = streamReader.ReadLine();
                    var parts = lineData.Split('|');
                    lineElements = parts.First().Split(':');                        
                    invoice = int.Parse(lineElements[0]);
                    invoicedate = (lineElements[1]);
                    term = int.Parse(lineElements[2]);
                    qty = int.Parse(lineElements[3]);
                    Console.WriteLine(invoice);
                    Console.WriteLine(invoicedate);
                    Console.WriteLine(term);
                    Console.WriteLine(qty);



                }
```

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: The header is not complete. There must be another between qty and description

Answer (score 0):

First define a structure that can hold the informations

```
public class InventoryData
{
    public string Inv { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Term { get; set; }
    public IList<InventoryArticle> Articles { get; set; }
}

public class InventoryArticle
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Whatever { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool Tax { get; set; }
}
```

then two methods, that will parse a single line into the structure

```
static InventoryData ParseInventoryData( string data )
{
    var parts = data.Split( '|' );
    var headparts = parts.First().Split( ':' );
    var result = new InventoryData
    {
        Inv = headparts[0],
        Date = DateTime.ParseExact( headparts[1], "yyyy/MM/dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ),
        Term = headparts[2],
        Articles = parts.Skip( 1 ).Select( part => ParseInventoryArticle( part ) ).ToList(),
    };
    return result;
}

static InventoryArticle ParseInventoryArticle( string data )
{
    var parts = data.Split( ':' );
    var result = new InventoryArticle
    {
        Quantity = int.Parse( parts[0] ),
        Whatever = parts[1],
        Description = parts[2],
        Price = decimal.Parse( parts[3], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ),
        Tax = parts[4] == "Y",
    };
    return result;
}
```

and finally how to parse the content of a file

```
string[] content = {
    "Inv #     Date     term qty description         price Tax",
    "3221409:2017/01/12:215|10:WD2002:2TB Hard Drive:121.66:N|20:KG240S:240GB SSD:125.10:N|20:KG120S:120GB SSD:78.75:N" };

var data = content
    // skip the header row
    .Skip( 1 ) 
    // parse the content
    .Select( row => ParseInventoryData( row ) ) 
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer this helps. The file doesn't have headers but I'm first trying to just parse the file and write to console and getting index was outside the bounds of the array. Below is my code.